# How to read value of selected item of drop down in Razor cshtml webmatrix

Tags: html, razor, drop-down-menu

```js
@ {

  var db = Database.Open("InventoryDB-D");

  var listAgent = "SELECT catID,catName FROM InvCategoryTBLD";

  List < SelectListItem > agentdropdownlistdata = new List < SelectListItem > ();
  bool isSelected = false;
  foreach(var item in db.Query(listAgent)) {
    testvalue = item.catName;
    agentdropdownlistdata.Add(new SelectListItem {
      Text = item.catName,
        Value = item.catID.ToString(),
        Selected = isSelected

    });
  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="" method="post">
    @Html.DropDownList("Agents", agentdropdownlistdata)
    <input type="submit" value="Droplist" name="DroplistX" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I need to read the value of the item selected in the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable and define it with a Request.Form instruction like this

```
 if(isPost){
  var Agents = Request.Form["Agents"];
 }
```

When you'll click on submit, the variable will be set to what is selected inside your dropdownlist...